# What device(s) I need for connecting two wireless LAN?

Tags: network

[image: I have two LAN, one LAN is for IP camera and one LAN is for]

IP cameras on ground floor connected to a wireless router, and there is an internet modem on third floor.

First of all, I want to extend ground floor wifi signal in order to connect to IP camera LAN from floor 3, I use a radio wireless access point in order to extend wifi signal of IP camera LAN

My question is this:

**What device(s) I need in order to:**

1. Connect to IP camera LAN from floor 3
2. Create a third network in which I can access both internet modem and IP camera LAN

Can I do this with a wireless router?

Comment: Given that (IP) cameras are usually security-relevant and wireless networks are *very* easily interrupted, I'd seriously recommend a wired approach. You'll need wiring between floors anyway for a business-grade solution.

Answer (score 2):

You will need several devices.  To my knowledge, there isn't a single device that does what you want.  On each floor, you will need wireless access points for the devices on each floor.  In addition, you will need two wireless devices that can function as a wireless bridge, linking the two floors together.

Please note that product recommendations are off topic on this SE.

Comment: Thanks Ron, so I need a router which I should set it as bridge mode (WISP) mode

Comment: And Can I use a wireless router to connect two lans?

Comment: You need access points (not routers) that can function as a bridge.